# API request using JS ES5 with Kerberos

Tags: api, authentication, kerberos, ecmascript-5

I need help with making a request to a server using Kerberos auth and I have a requirement to achieve the same using JS ES5.

I have already looked for any existing library to achieve it but could not find any.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what language are you trying to work in?

Comment: @MattAndruff I was referring to the Javascript ES5 version, with no node libraries involved.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. But...

Node.js does have libraries so if you meant Node.js and said JS well that might workout for you.

The longer answer is, most modern browsers support SPNEGO which is a standard that can negotiate [kerberos].  So although Javascript doesn't support it you can redirect the browser to authenticate SPNEGO.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Could you please point out how that browser redirection can be achieved?